# Encrypt/sign a client-to-API request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, security, sign

We are building a JSON API on top of our Web application, using [JSONAPI::Resources](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) to expose endpoints and [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper) to handle user authentication.

Most of our API endpoints will be exposed only to authenticated users, and Doorkeeper will probably do a great job at enforcing that. But we still have a couple endpoints that will not be authenticated: signup, login, account confirmation, and maybe a couple others.

I am worried that letting those API endpoints completely open will expose us to attacks, in the form of spamming new accounts for example.

1. Maybe I am worrying more than necessary? Do APIs usually let this kind of endpoint unsecure, and add prevention systems like throttling? ([Rack::Attack!!!](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack)?)
2. If not, is signing (or encrypting) my requests before sending them to the API server the right approach?
3. And if that's so, do you have any recommendation, or preferred approach, in doing so?

I tried to Google keywords like "rails api sign request" or "rails api encrypt request", but I'm not sure the results are pertinent, or which one would be recommended.

The first clients that will talk to this API will be Android then iOS applications, and we might add in the future client-side web applications (at the moment, our web application is monolithic and does not use the API).

Comment: I think none of these questions is specific to Ruby. I therefore recommend you ask on [security](http://security.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes My last question, maybe not clearly, asks for suggestions of implementations for a Ruby on Rails server.

Comment: OK, but that requires an answer for (2) first. That's the reason why you should ask followup questions instead of multiple questions at the same time. Hint: If you are not authenticated, how can you sign? Anybody can encrypt...

Comment: You can of course integrate a secret in your applications and use that to setup a TLS connection with client authentication, but as the secret will be visible to attackers, it will only give limited protection. TLS in general is of course a good idea...